# Give this function an id

Tags: javascript

We are making a advert div, and we have this function on mouse over and mouse out an effect takes place. The issue is I cannot run more than one of these functions on same page, I suppose because it does not possess an ID.

Code is

```
Function mouseOver ()
{
    document.getelementbyid("flashdiv").classname="flash-abg";
}
Function mouseOut ()
{
    document.getelementbyid("flashdiv").classname="flash-I";
}
```

So how would I. Run two of these on one page, I am on iPad so difficult to set styling on here, etc. So apologies.

Basically the above code accompanies HTML and CSS to display hover effect on a advert div, we have all divs working correctly individually but because we have no I'd for the functions, they don't work together correctly when we have more than one on a page. As you can see I am crap at js.

Comment: Functions don't have IDs. State your REAL PROBLEM as opposed to [what you *think* might be it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - I think he knows what his problem is, just the phrasing of the title is a little misleading.

Comment: I apologize if I haven't titled correctly. The function above works on a particular element, but clashes if we add it to another element. I thought it may need an I'd or whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the same function to be binded to different elements, if correclty binded *this* is a reference to the source of the event (the div to which the event is attached). That should allow you to bind the same function to different elements. In your code just replace *document.getelementbyid("flashdiv")* for *this*.

Comment: Thanks,but isn't that a function of jquery ? So I would use document.this("flashdiv").classname="flash-abg";  ?

Comment: @422 - No, no, you would use `this.className = "flash-abg";`

Comment: Yeah this is simple and effective, but only if "flashdiv" is the same element the mouse events happen at.

Comment: The HTML I have is <div class="ihover" onmouseover="mouseover()" onmouseout="mouseout()"></div>

Comment: If that div is the same div to which you want to apply the *flash-* style, then this code should work. If not you should use Jürgen's solution, as it allows you to specify which div to use.

Comment: thanks,we should get Internet tomorrow. I will post a fiddle and come back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are event handlers, we are missing the code registering them. You could write a function taking the id which returns an event handler for one div in the following way:

```
function createMouseOver(id) {
    return function () {
        document.getelementbyid(id).classname="flash-abg";
    }
}
```

Then register the result of createMouseOver('someid'), which is a function with the correct id in its closure.

Alternatively, don't use ids at all and find all your ad divs by class -- and register event handlers for all elements found by class.