# How to make these functions work on same page

Tags: javascript

My phrasing is probably all wrong, but this is what I have.

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/Ute6B/

Now this works fine, its for an ad system I am making nothing earth shattering.

The above example is a banner.

Now if I add this code: ASWELL ( it all goes pear shaped ) so I am obviously a knob, and have cocked something up. As functions cannot have ID's i gather it must be the mouse events that are colliding, so not allowing the feature I have made work independantly on both codes... essentially, if you add the code below to the fiddle... bugger that, I will create a secondary fiddle.. with 2 sets of code. added for you to see the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/9zcqW/

The idea is that each of the Adverts is unique, and the function on hover for the info links works independantly on each advert, in some cases we may need 4 adverts per page... so really any help appreciated... my previous post here::: may shed some light to answers already received, we didnt have internet when I posted that so now this is updated version in this question...

[Give this function an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061112/give-this-function-an-id)

Comment: not sure what you edited Matt ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just give the functions unique names? `mouseOverBanner` and `mouseOverSidebar`, for example?

Comment: If I knew how, I wouldnt ask.. I just dont know how to do it...

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with unique function names. http://jsfiddle.net/playerace/9trjw/ But if you intend to create a general function, it can be done too. But you need to pass some paramater.

Comment: [I updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zcqW/1/) and it looks like it works. All you have to do is change the names of the functions, both in the JavaScript and in the HTML `onmouseover`/`onmouseout` events.

Comment: Thanks @sdleihssirhc just how I want it perfick ! Thanks.

Comment: @ace that is cool too... bugger I dont know which is best to use now lolol.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this also i am not sure it's perfect way or not but it's work

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qCZU6/)

javascript

```
function mouseOver(ban_id)
{
    if(ban_id=="flashdivb")
        document.getElementById("flashdivb").className="flash-abgb";
    else if(ban_id=="flashdivsb")
            document.getElementById("flashdivsb").className="flash-abgsb";
}
function mouseOut(ban_id)
{
    if(ban_id=="flashdivb")
        document.getElementById("flashdivb").className="flash-ib";
    else if(ban_id=="flashdivsb")
            document.getElementById("flashdivsb").className="flash-isb";
}
```

html

```
<!--html code for the banner-->
<div class="banner">
         <div class="bannerAd">
            <img src="http://sitehelp.com.au/images/bannerad.png">
            <a href="somelink.html">
                <div id="flashdivb" class="flash-ib"></div>
            </a>

            <a href="/media">
                <div class="ibhover" onmouseover="mouseOver('flashdivb')" onmouseout="mouseOut('flashdivb')"> </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--html code for the sidebar-->
<div class="sidebar">
         <div class="sidebarAd">
            <img src="http://sitehelp.com.au/images/sidebarad.png">
            <a href="somelink.html">
                <div id="flashdivsb" class="flash-isb"></div>
            </a>

            <a href="/media">
                <div class="isbhover" onmouseover="mouseOver('flashdivsb')" onmouseout="mouseOut('flashdivsb')"> </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
/*css for the banner*/
h3 { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#444444;

}
/*header advert*/
.banner {
width:468px;
height:60px;
border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
position:relative;
}
.bannerAd{
position:absolute;
top:0px;left:0px;
}
.flash-ib {
    background-image: url("http://sitehelp.com.au/images/bannerinfo.png");
    height: 60px;
    width: 468px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;
    /*opacity:0.4;opacity option*/
}
.flash-abgb {
    background-image: url("http://sitehelp.com.au/images/bannerinfolink.png");
    height: 60px;
    width: 468px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;
    /*opacity:0.8;opacity option*/
}
div.ibhover {
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 443px;
}
/*css for the sidebar*/
.sidebar {
width:250px;
height:250px;
border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
position:relative;
}
.sidebarAd{
position:absolute;
top:0px;left:0px;
}
.flash-isb {
    background-image: url("http://sitehelp.com.au/images/sidebarinfo.png");
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;
    /*opacity:0.4;opacity option*/
}
.flash-abgsb {
    background-image: url("http://sitehelp.com.au/images/sidebarinfolink.png");
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;
    /*opacity:0.8;opacity option*/
}
div.isbhover {
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 225px;
}
```